# one server in mongodb sharded cluster is having high cpu

Tags: mongodb

We have five sharded cluster in these 1 instance is getting high cpu.

when we check the cpu of 5 shards remaing 4 instances will be having 20% but in 1 instance it will reach more than 90%

how can i decrease the load on 1 instance?

Comment: This is very limited data to diagnose something like that.

Comment: This seems a symptom of incorrectly chosen shard key. Check out [this offical doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/) and see if it is feasible to review and change existing shard key.